# How to vertically align 2 different sizes of text whereas one of them is aligned to the right?

Tags: html, css

Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3998033/1219728) answer to the question how to vertically align 2 different sizes of text. As it is stated in the comments *"this seems to fail if I want the second span to be right floated. Then its aligned on top. Any ideas how to make it work with float?"*. The example given in the comments can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lszdx2hd/):

HTML:

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<body>
<div> 
  <span>100</span>
  <span>This is the desc</span> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
height:200px;
width:300px;
margin:auto;
background:red;
border:1px solid #f00;
font-size: 40px;
}
span {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
padding:0 10px;

}
span + span { 
  font-size:50%; float: right; 
}
```

I stumbled across the same problem and would like to open this as a new question, as the other is already answered and it seems unlikely that the answer will be updated on its own.

Comment: so you want to have both span in middle..? currently this is desc is little bit on top..you want both in middle?

Comment: sorry as i think i got confused and used line hight.sorry my bad..

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/5u5mk9hk/

Answer (score 1):

`flexbox` can do this if floating is **not** a requirement.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background: orange;
  font-size: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}
p {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
p:first-of-type {
  font-size: 50px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>100</p>
  <p>This is the desc</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, I do not believe this can be done with float alone (obviously I would be happy to be proved otherwise!), however there may be a way around this which may hopefully help. Please see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lszdx2hd/4/).

You can vertically center elements using position absolute, even without knowing the height of the element, by doing something like:

```
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Full explanation can be found [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

Hope that helps in some way?