# Perfectly vertical align top of fonts of 2 different text sizes using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this design: 
[image: example]

Note that both text  are perfectly top aligned but I'm almost sure this is impossible to achieve in CSS in a scalable way (I mean not hardcoding pixels with position relative/top for example).

Using flex looked like a good way to achieve this but since this is text, the top alignment is correct but based on the text 'bounding box' but the letters '77' don't take up 100% height of that box, causing it to not be perfectly aligned.

I understand why this happens since letter 'a' doesn't take up the same space as letter 'X' but I was just wondering if someone can find out a very nice tricky to achieve this design.

Here are my two attempts at this:

```css
div#a {
  
  background:#EEE;
  line-height: 1;
}


span {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

#b {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
 <div id="a">
        <span style=" font-size: 48px;">77</span>
        <span style="font-size:14px;;">USD</span>
    </div>

<div id="b">
  <div style=" font-size: 48px; line-height: 48px;">77</div>
  <div style=" font-size: 14px;">USD</div>
</div>
```

(please note there is a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997983/how-to-vertically-align-2-different-sizes-of-text) issue but they didn't want 'perfect' alignment like this)

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use this approach and tuning the `line-height` property.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div .container span {
  line-height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="container">
    <span style=" font-size: 48px;">77</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <span style="font-size:14px;">USD</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="b">
  <div class="container">
    <span style=" font-size: 48px;">100</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <span style="font-size:14px;">USD</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks amazing and somewhat scalable (you can change font-sizes with success). Is there a rationale behind this or just testing it out until you got it right? 

It seems you found like the % of height that the numbers occupy on the 'text bounding box'. Obviously this could change for different font family and if instead of 100 you try to type 'xyz'. Still a bit better than just position relative/top the elements

Comment: Hi @AlfaTeK, You are right. I found the percent number that fits better inside the bounding box. There isn't any trick here. It's just trial and error. Texts are boring, they have different `line-height` and is very difficult to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

MDN documentation indicates that modifying the value of `span { vertical align: text-top; }` by replacing *text-top* with *super* (or *50% to shift the baseline) will help you accomplish your objective!

I learned this while preparing to suggest that you replace the aforementioned declaration with the HTML `<sup>` tag, which enables 'superscript' on specified inline text.

Check out documentation and decide what works best for your project~
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup

Comment: I fail to see how that works: https://jsfiddle.net/zpf0cxkt/ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try modifying the HTML ```<div id="a">
       <h1> 77
        <span style="font-size:14px;">USD</span></h1>
    </div>``` and adding a ```line-height``` rule with a value of ```2em```. Although not best practice, I like how the ```<sup>``` tag displays content under circumstance similar to yours!